# CorePlot candleStick chart boxes fill color

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I am using a candletick plot in CorePlot. However could not find the property to change the color of the boxes of the candlestick .Whats the property for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `increaseFill` and `decreaseFill`. If you need to change the colors for different data points, there are datasource methods to provide different fills for each data index.